# How to take a screenshot in Android from a background service programmatically and return a bitmap

Tags: android, background, screenshot

I read nearly every answer here. Is there any way to capture a screenshot from a background service, which will return a bitmap?
I know I can do a screenshot with AccessibilityService and/or MediaProjectionApi with an invisible Activity. But in every solution the image is saved (at least temporary) on the device. Which I prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, you got your bitmap.

```
/** Take Screen Shot */
private void takeScreenshot() {
    try {
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + uniqueID + "_" + getEventTimeLocal() + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        //// then we can delete your file
        deleteScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        Log.i(TAG, "exception': " + e.printStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs a View and therefore an Activity. Ok here it's saved, that could be removed, but it doesn't seem to help.